# Future best bounds for the Prime Counting function

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers

I asked myself, that in the future, what are the best possible bounds on the prime counting function.
I am talking about perfect bounds for it.
And what I mean by this is that these bounds are some two functions that have a positive second and negative third derivative. (This implies, that the bounds are 1. always increasing, 2. increasing slower over time).
Now, I tried to compute these bounds by hand for the first few integers and before I can explain my problem, I will try to explain my process.
$$$$
Upper bound:
if $\pi(x) \le \frac{\pi(a+k)-\pi(a)}{k} \times (x-a)+\pi(a)$, for every $x$ then $a$ and $k$ must be parts of the upper bound. This is easy to explain. What I am doing is finding the next integer ($a+k$) that if embedded in the secant with $a$, forms a secant that is bigger than all other values of the prime counting function.

$$$$
Lower Bound: If $\pi(x) \ge \frac{\pi(a+k)-\pi(a)}{k} \times (x-a)+\pi(a)$ for every $a \le x \le b$, and $\frac {\pi(a)-\pi(a-o)}{p} \ge \frac {\pi(a+k)-\pi(a)}{k} \ge \frac {\pi(a+k+m)-\pi(a+k)}{m}$, and $k$ is minimal, then $a$ and $k$ must be part of the lower bound. This is basically the same rule as for the upper bound, we want to form secants that go through the lowest points (the points that are the biggest anomaly to the "average of the function"), but additionally, we want the second derivative to be positive and third derivative to be negative. (Derivative in this case means, that if we were to draw a lines through all the points we would get a new function).

Note: Negative derivative can also be $0$, this would not change the question.

Now after all of this, I drew some graphs and connected the points, the first few integers for the Upper Bound are:
$$S_U= 2, 3, 5, 7, 13, 19, 23, 31, 43, ...$$
($S_U$ denotes the sequence of the Upper Bound)

and respectively:
$$S_L= 2, 3, 5, 7 , 11, 59, ...$$

($S_L$ denotes the sequence of the Lower Bound).

Now, one can think of some patterns, using even in the short sequences:

1. The first twin of a twin prime will never be an Upper Bound Prime. (For Primes bigger than 2)
2. The last twin of a twin prime will never be a Lower Bound Prime.  (For Primes bigger than 3)
   $$$$
   Here are some further rules, I came up with:

The first of two primes, with distance k to one another will never be an Upper Bound Prime, except for the first time this happens.
The last of two primes with a distance k to  one another will never be a Lower Bound Prime, except for the first time this happens.

Now I am trying to explain my problem:

After "programming" a spreadsheat to help me find the next Upper and Lower Bound Primes something interesting occured. The Lower Bound Prime Sequence had a huge jump:
$$S_L = 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 59, 67, 71, 79, 83, 89, 97, 7433, 7489, 7529$$

And there is an explaination for this:
Since I want to have a decreasing derivative that tends towards zero as x tends towards infinity, I can not have an indent in this Sequence (Again, to visualize, think of connecting the points with lines). Now the derivative of this function can be expressed as a series of derivatives, these are the derivatives of the lines, that connect the Lower Bound Primes:
$$S_L' = 1, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{6}, \frac{1}{8}, \frac{1}{8}, \frac{1}{8}, \frac{1}{8}$$
As you can see, the Sequence of derivatives is decreasing and tending towards zero.
Now, this jump happens because of the secant between $89<x<97$. This secant undershoots strongly and needs a long time to "reach" the prime counting function again.
For a visual representation, see this: $\ref {https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+1%2F8*%28x-89%29%2B24+from+0+to+8000%2C+plot+x%2F%28ln%28x%29-1%29+from+0+to+8000}$

This causes the huge jump in the sequence.

Ultimately Using this method no "perfect" (as in the definition of Lower and Upper Bound that was established beforehand) Lower Bound can be established. However this formula will work on the Upper Bound since the only thing that could ever cause a jump would be a giant prime gap followed by several small prime gaps.

Anyway, if you have any Idea on how to get a sequence of Lower Bound Primes, please submit them, as I really want to see a Solution to this.

As a finishing touch, here is the extended list of upper bound primes:
$$S_U = 2, 3, 5, 7, 13, 19, 23, 31, 43, 47, 73, 113, 199, 283, 467, 661, 887, 1129, 1327, 1627, 2803, 3947, 4297, 5881, 6379, 7043, 9949, 10343, 13187, 15823, 18461, 24137, 33647, 34763, 37663, 42863, 43067, 59753, 59797, 82619, 96017, 102679, 129643, 130699, 142237, 155893, 187477, 194119, 210533, 211949, 230393, 267961, 272423, 284839, 328129, 338477, 355111, 395323, 445033, 501233, ...$$

(This is not definite, since I only tested using Primes up to $10^6$ therefore, strong fluctuations in the Prime Counting function can change some of these values, however I did check these values also using the approximation of Dusart which gives an Upper Bound for the Prime Counting function and the "derivative" of the connecting lines was always greater than the derivative of the approximation).

Edit: I found that this question might be similar to the question of inscribing a convex polygon within another polygon. If we let  $y=\pi(x)$ as well as $(\infty|-\infty)$ be the vertices of the polygon, inscribing a convex polygon within this polygon would give a lower bound (which is the ultimate quest here). I found this article explaining a neat algorithm for this.

[Inscribed and circumscribed non-regular polygons] [1]
[1]: [Inscribing convex polygon within simple polyon](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1852720/inscribing-convex-polygon-within-simple-polyon)

$$$$
I still may be wrong in some of these points, so I want to hear your suggestions as well. Thank you.

Comment: What are the constraints on the type of function that forms the bounds? If there are none, then $\pi(n)\le \pi(n)\le \pi(n)$ forms perfect bounds. Surely, the motivation of theorems like the PNT is to find a compromise between the advantage of a less complex, well understood function like $\operatorname{Li}(n)$ or $\ln (n)$ and the disadvantage of imperfect bounds?

Comment: I am talking about functions with a positive second derivative and negative third derivative. Edit: What I am searching for are the best bounds of this kind, since the prime counting function is always fluctuating, just as any step function it would has to has some bound on the max fluctuation. For example the floor function fluctuates between y=x and y=x-1.

Comment: maybe a better example would be some function like f(x) = floor(sqrt(x)+sin(x)), this function always lies between sqrt(x)+sin(x) and sqrt(x)+sin(x)-1, but what i am searching for are bounds like this: sqrt(x)+1 as an upper bound and sqrt(x)-2 for the lower bound.  https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7Bsqrt%28x%29%2Bsin%28x%29%2C+sqrt%28x%29%2Bsin%28x%29-1%2C+sqrt%28x%29%2B1%2C+sqrt%28x%29-2%2C+floor%28sqrt%28x%29%2Bsin%28x%29%29%7D%2C+plot+from+0+to+100